# How to make sense of the "CreationTime" and other times in Ehcache Elements?

Tags: java, ehcache, jodatime

In the [Ehcache Api for Element](http://ehcache.org/apidocs/net/sf/ehcache/Element.html), the javadocs give no information on how the various times are represented. They're simply a long.

Is it safe to assume that this is the millisecond instant? I'm using the JodaTime library for times, so if I create a DateTime this way, would it be accurate?

```
DateTime time = new DateTime(element.getCreationTime());
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes the "long" returned by element.getCreationTime() (as well as the other time() methods of the class Element) are the specified number of milliseconds since the standard base time known as "the epoch".

Hence "new java.util.Date(element.getCreationTime())" or "new org.joda.time.DateTime(element.getCreationTime())" would work the same.

You should be able to test this really easily though...
For example, I would have tested and made sure the element.getCreationTime() shows the same when using java.util.Date and org.joda.time.DateTime and printing them both to screen

Hope that helped.

Comment: I appreciate the response, but I don't think your test mechanism is accurate. Both java.util.Date and org.joda.time.DateTime would have the same (invalid) result even if the long represented something else. Comparing them against each other doesn't prove anything. That said, I can't imagine what else the long could represent. I wish the javadocs were better.

Comment: Good point about the comparison...that does not prove an accurate time. I'll be more specifics next time. But the answer is still valid. An equally simple test (which is what i was thinking of while writing my answer) would be to add something to the cache, and right after get if from cache + print the new org.joda.time.DateTime(element.getCreationTime())...verifying that it is actually the right time (you know that since you just added it). About the javadocs, could be possibly better...Feel free to create a JIRA at http://jira.terracotta.org/jira/browse/EHC (documentation component)